# When Sharepoint server 2016 Release Date?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, release

Please provide SharePoint Server 2016 release date? Please share any link for this. I searched in Google and found out release date is May 2016. I am not sure about this date? So anyone know about release date please share with me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are asking 3 questions in one. Please do ask only one question per post

Comment: doesn't this question suits more in http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft have not yet released the release date for final product

However I think  the RTM(release-to-manufacturing) release date was on March 14 for Sharepoint 2016 [link1](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/03/14/microsoft-releases-sharepoint-server-2016.aspx)

For SharePoint 2016 RC(Release Candidate)/SharePoint 2016 Preview I think the date is around August 2016

[link2](https://www.itunity.com/article/sharepoint-2016-preview-released-august-2283)

[link3](http://connectedsystems.com/news/Latest%20News/SharePoint-2016-new-and-deprecated-features.aspx)

Comment: I was gone through the above link i am not getting RTM of SharePoint Server 2016 and SharePoint Server 2016 this both same or different.Please someone know tell me.

Comment: No they are not both. RTM versions are typically released to manufacturers  so that the manufacturers can work out any bugs the software may encounter.https://blogs.office.com/2016/03/14/sharepoint-2016-rtm-and-the-future-of-sharepoint-event/.............Sharepoint 2016 RC is  is a beta version with potential to be a final product, which is ready to release unless significant bugs emerge..https://blogs.office.com/2016/01/20/sharepoint-server-2016-and-project-server-2016-release-candidate-available/

Comment: After testing the  RTM versions the Final product SharePoint Server 2016 should be released, After that only  developers work on that and migrating SharePoint  2013 to SharePoint 2016.what i was understanding is a Right..?

Comment: FInal Sharepoint 2016 has not been relased.Yes after RTM the final product will be released shortly(I think in May).

Comment: Thank you so much Amit. Sorry to ask so many questions,One more doubt  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51493 in this link download option is there for Sharepoint 2016. This is a RTM version for manufacturers.

Comment: Yes thats RTM version.You can use it as trial version to check out the new features of Sharepoint 2016. you can get 180 days trial product key from Install instruction tab from above link

Answer (score 0):

It was released May 4, 2016 with the event [The Future of SharePoint](https://blogs.office.com/2016/05/04/the-future-of-sharepoint/) discussing [SharePoint Server 2016—your foundation for the future](https://blogs.office.com/2016/05/04/sharepoint-server-2016-your-foundation-for-the-future/).

The download link of SharePoint Server 2016 is http://aka.ms/GetSharePoint2016.